# .htaccess authentication with wordpress

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, authentication, pretty-urls

OK, I have an area on my wordpress site, **home/gallery/test** and I want to restrict access to it using .htaccess. Setting up authentication for a directory using .htaccess is pretty straightforward. But my problem in wordpress is that **home/gallery/test** doesn't actually exist as a directory anywhere because I'm using pretty URLs.

So, while I can stick the authentication block in the .htaccess located in the home directory, this then requests authentication for the entire site. I am at a loss to know where to locate the .htaccess file to limit access to just **home/gallery/test**.

Any thoughts? Can I set something up in the home directory .htaccess file to understand that it isn't the entire site but just the **home/gallery/test** URL that I want to protect?

For information, here's the contents of my htaccess file (updated to include the suggested solution).

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "^/home/gallery/test$" protected

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Forbidden"
AuthUserFile /home/xxxxx/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=protected
Satisfy any

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(failed_auth\.html).*$ [NC]
RewriteRule . - [L]
</IfModule> 

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a solution using `mod_setenvif`

```
SetEnvIfNoCase REQUEST_URI "^/home/gallery/test" PROTECTED

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Test protection"
AuthUserFile /path/to/passwords_file
Require valid-user
Satisfy any
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=PROTECTED
```

---

EDIT: taking your htaccess code into consideration, it should look like this

```
SetEnvIfNoCase REQUEST_URI "^/home/gallery/test" PROTECTED

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Forbidden"
AuthUserFile /home/xxxxx/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
Satisfy any
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=PROTECTED

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteRule ^failed_auth\.html$ - [L]

  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After some playing around, it seems that for some reason this is still not requesting authentication and I am able to freely access that url. Any ideas?

Comment: I just tested my code and it's working as expected on my side. Where is your htaccess located ?

Comment: It's located in the public HTML directory. I wonder if there is something wordpress is doing that's messing it up. I've hunted around and tried a few different variations of what you gave in your original post but to no avail.

Comment: Wait, i read back again your question and i think i misunderstood. I thought `home/gallery/test` was a url but actually you meant 3 distinct folder `home`, `gallery` and `test` ?

Comment: No you are correct, home/gallery/test is a url. I can't figure out why the htaccess lines you suggest don't work. I see no reason for it!

Comment: Do you have other rules (or something else) in your root htaccess ? Do you have other htaccess in subfolders ?

Comment: I have edited my original post to include the contents of the htaccess file (updated with your suggestion). There are no other htaccess files I can find.

Comment: You have to remove `$` after `test` in first line. Otherwise, only url `/home/gallery/test` will be matched but not `/home/gallery/test/` or `/home/gallery/test/XXX`

Comment: I edited my answer with the final result (how your htaccess should look like)

Comment: Nope, unfortunately it's still allowing access and not coming up with any authentication request at all. I've tried it with different URLs with the same result. Quite bizarre.

Comment: Could you tell me which url you're trying to reach ?

Comment: the site is thealmondgrinder.com and i want to limit access to some of the projects there. for example, the iCandy project. having fiddled endlessly with the directives in htaccess, i seem to be able to either impose a site-wide authentication request, or none at all.

Comment: I see only `/gallery/` folder for this project. My code is made to protect only path `/home/gallery/test`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67939/discussion-between-drnofruit-and-justin-iurman).

Comment: I have accepted your answer above as it does seem to be the correct thing to do. However, i believe there's something odd going on with wordpress that is preventing it from working and have bypassed the issue by creating a php function to handle this with roles and permissions instead for now. Many thanks for your help. If i figure out what was happening I'll let you all know.